# Script to add balise [img][/img] on each line of text linux?

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I just got a script who upload image file on to a web hoster; at the end I got a file with all the links (one link per line) and I would like to add `[img]` at the beginning of each link and `[/img]` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, with the stream editor, sed:

```
sed -e 's/^/[img]/' -e 's!$![/img]!' < input > output
```

Here I've changed the delimiter for the second search & replacement from `/` to `!` so that the forward-slash in the replacement text doesn't need to be escaped. GNU sed would allow an in-place edit with the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/[img]/' -e 's!$![/img]!' input
```

Alternatively, you could edit the file in-place with `ed`:

```
ed -s input <<< $'1,$s/^/[img]/\n1,$s!$![/img]!\nw\nq'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to add `[img]` to the start of each line in a file, and `[/img]` to the end, you could do that with `awk` like so:

```
awk '{ print "[img]" $0 "[/img]" }' infile >outfile
```

Or,

```
awk '{ printf("[img]%s[/img]\n", $0) }' infile >outfile
```